# IAC: How to deal with removing components from Azure using pipelines and bicep

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-resource-manager, masstransit, infrastructure-as-code, azure-bicep

We're creating / updating our environments running a bicep file during an Azure DevOps pipeline.

As part of this, we're creating our Azure Service Bus. The topics/subscriptions/queues in the bus are created through code with MassTransit.

Due to some configuration changes in MassTransit, we've now some subscriptions and queues in the Azure Service Bus, which are not used anymore (but where not removed through MassTransit). We want to get rid of this subscriptions and queues (in a scripted, automated way, triggered by our pipeline).

What are best practices to deal with such a scenario (removing azure components, created outside the bicep file)?

Comment: Consider using an az cli script task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I second what TrevorBrooks has suggested. You may have a task using Az CLI / Az PowerShell / Az REST API.